# How to tell a setup file to install to the Documents folder with Inno Setup compiler?

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I'm trying to create a setup file using Inno Setup Compiler, and I want it to install to the Documents folder as it needs to create and then delete a file, something that it can't do if it installs to Program Files. I've tried using `%userprofile%\Documents` as that works in File Explorer, but that simply creates a folder called `%userprofile%` wherever the Setup.exe is, and  `C:\Users\%username%\Documents` simply creates the `%username%` folder in the Users folder. How do I get it to install into the Documents folder no matter where it is?

Comment: Don't install to the document folder. Install to Program Files like you're supposed to. If there are non-document data files that your program needs to create and delete, store them in the Application Data folder. Your development tool should provide a method of discovering that location at run time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*While @GTAVLover is right,* you will most probably want to use the [`{userdocs}` or `{commondocs}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=userdocs) in standard Inno Setup sections, likes [`[Files]`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection).

The syntax is like:

```
[Files]
Source: "readme.txt"; DestDir: "{userdocs}"
```

---

Had you wanted to refer to environment variables (what is not the right way in this case), use [`{%NAME}`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=name) syntax:

```
[Files]
Source: "readme.txt"; DestDir: "{%USERPROFILE}\Documents"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use Inno Setup Shell Folder Constants to do this.

See more at [Inno Setup Help.](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts)

Use `ExpandConstant('{userdocs}')` where you want to get path of Documents folder (For current user).

It will return `"OS Drive:\Users\CurrentUser\Documents"`.

Eg:

```
MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{userdocs}'), mbInformation, MB_OK);
```

For all users, you should replace `userdocs` with `commondocs`.

So, It will return `"OS Drive:\Users\Public\Documents"`.